# How to prioritize regex | (OR) expressions?

Tags: php, regex, alternation

I'm trying to match kanji compounds in a Japanese sentence using regex.

Right now, I'm using `/ ((.)*) /`to match a space delimited compound in, for example, `彼はそこに ひと人 でいた。`

The problem is, that in some sentence the word is at the beginning, or followed with a punctuation characters. Ex. `いっ瞬 の間が生まれた。` or `一昨じつ、彼らはそこを出発した。`

I've tried something like `/ ((.)*) |^((.)*) | ((.)*)、 etc.` But this matches `彼はそこに ひと人` instead of `ひと人` in `彼はそこに ひと人 でいた。`

Is there any way to pack all this in a single regex, or do I have to use one, check whether it returned anything, then try another one if not?

Thanks!

P.S.: I'm using PHP to parse the sentences.

Comment: Have you tried using a word boundary (`\b`)?

Comment: What language/regular expression implementation do you use?

Comment: \b doesn't seem to help, or even work with Japanese.

Comment: `\b` should certainly work on Unicode. The problem is that PHP is typically **but not always** built with a version of PCRE that has been compiled not to work well with Unicode.  Sometimes you can make it better with `//u`, but sometimes you cannot. If you did not personally, explicitly, and manually configure and compile your own dedicated build of the PCRE library **by hand** and then do the same thing all over again with your own special installation of PHP, you cannot rely on its regular expressions working reliably on Unicode. You need a different language if you want reliability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it for a long time I believe there's no way to parse the compounds without delimiting them all with spaces or any other characters which is what I'm doing now :)

Ex. if the sentence is `私は ノート、ペンなどが必要だ。`, there is no way for the computer to know whether it's `私は` (start sentence & space delimited) or `ノート` (space & comma delimited) that is the right it should choose.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

I think this: `/([^ 、]+)/` should match the words in examples you've given (you may want to add some other word-terminating chars apart from space and 、 if you have them in your texts (or use `\pL` instead of `[^ 、]` to cover all UTF letters.

**EXAMPLE**

```
<?                                                                                                                                                          
preg_match_all('/[^ 、]+/u', "彼らは日本の 国民 となった。", $m);
print_r($m);
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 彼らは日本の
            [1] => 国民
            [2] => となった。
        )
)
```

Comment: When I use `/([^ 、]*)/` on `彼らは日本の 国民 となった。` it returns `彼らは日本の 国民`, not `国民`. `/ ((.)*?) /` returns `国民` for `彼らは日本の 国民 となった。` (correct), but nothing for `いっ瞬 の間が生まれた。` where the word is at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is in UTF-8 you could try with

```
'/(\pL+)/u'
```

The `\pL+` matches one or more letter in the string.

Example:

```
$str = '彼はそこに ひと人 でいた。';

preg_match_all('/(\pL+)/u', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "彼はそこに"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "ひと人"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "でいた"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying only to split your string according to some pattern (white space, or punctuation), is that true??
what about this?

```
In [51]: word = '.test test\n.test'
In [53]: re.split('[\s,.]+',word)
Out[53]: ['', 'test', 'test', 'test']
```